# Syncing a YouTube Video for viewers in PHP

Tags: php, youtube

I'm working on something that my friends and I can use to sync up YouTune videos based on a URL. I'd like to do this myself instead of using another site just because it's a lot more fun!

So I've been looking around and I've found nothing that can help me with the issue I'm having (Syncing the videos), and help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Include code/your efforts so far on this matter.

Comment: Is this a coding question or youtube usability question? The `t` parameter will start a youtube video at the given time. `&t=30` will start a video at 30 seconds..

Answer (score 0):

good starting point is [start here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#playsinline) using javascript you need to store the position of the current playing vedio ajax would be good choice for string the position and return it back from back end storage (db)